# Spring Security - securing REST API

Tags: spring, api, rest, security, authentication

I am using Spring Security to secure a REST API.
I use a custom filter which checks if requests contain a valid JWT Token in the header. If the request contains a valid token, an authentication object is added to the security context, otherwise i add null to the security context.

I have also defined an AuthenticationEntryPoint which simply returns 401 when there is an Authentication Exception.

In my security xml, i define a series of intercept-urls. Some of them have access set to "isAuthenticated()" and some have access set to "permitAll".

When i make a request to a URL that has access set to "isAuthenticated()" with a valid JWT token in the header, that works fine. However, when i make a request with no token to a URL with access set to 'permitAll', an exception is thrown and 401 is returned.

What i want to achieve is a 401 response only being made when an unauthenticated request tries to access a URL with access set to 'isAuthenticated()'. When a request is made to a URL with access set to 'permitAll', i dont want 401 to be returned, whether the request is authenticated or not.

Comment: Post relevant codes such as security configs, auth filter and entry point